# sql UPDATE, a calculation is used multiple times, can it just be calculated once?

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

Using:

```
UPDATE `play`
   SET `counter1` = `counter1` + LEAST(`maxchange`, FLOOR(`x` / `y`) ), 
       `counter2` = `counter2` - LEAST(`maxchange`, FLOOR(`x` / `y`) ), 
       `x` = MOD(`x`, `y`) 
 WHERE `x` > `y` 
   AND `maxchange` > 0
```

As you can see, `LEAST(maxchange, FLOOR(x / y) )` is used multiple times, but it should always have the same value.  Is there a way to optimize this, to only calculate once?

I'm coding this in PHP, for the record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database engine query optimizer should optimize that away.

If you want to be sure check the [explain plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html). I do not think MySQL supports explaining updates, but it uses the same query optimizer as SELECT so you might have to translate it to a select.